# Adding an item to an observablearray in knockoutjs when using mapping

Tags: knockout.js

I am mapping some JSON to an observablearray called roles and displaying it on my page. This works fine. I have now added a couple of input fields since I would like to add some items to the array calling addRole on my model. But how do I get the values I have entered in my input fields in the self.addRole below ?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: roles" id="rolesContainer">
 <li><div data-bind="attr:{class: css}"></div><span data-bind="text: rolename"></span></li>
</ul>
<div  id="rolesContainer2">
 <input data-bind='value: rolename' />
 <input data-bind='value: css' />
 <button data-bind="click: addRole">Add</button> 
</div>


var roleViewModel=new RoleModel();
function RoleModel(){
    var self=this;
    self.roles=ko.observableArray();

    self.addRole = function(item) {
        self.roles.push({ name: item.rolename, css: item.css });
    };
}

function getRolesSuccess(data) {
    roleViewModel.roles=ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(roleViewModel, $("#rolesContainer")[0]);   
    ko.applyBindings(roleViewModel, $("#rolesContainer2")[0]);    
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define observable properties in your `RoleModel` for the two input fields: `css` and `rolename`. Then you need to use these two properties in your `addRole` method

```
function RoleModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.roles = ko.observableArray();
    self.rolename = ko.observable();
    self.css = ko.observable();
    self.addRole = function (item) {
        self.roles.push({
            rolename: self.rolename(),
            css: self.css()
        });
        self.rolename(null);
        self.css(null);
    };
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exetS/).

Side note: the call `roleViewModel.roles=ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` should be `roleViewModel.roles(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));` because your code overrides the already existing observable array with a new one, while the other keeps the observablearray just assigns a new value to it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the ko.mapping would actually define the properties, so I wouldn't have to?

Comment: No, the mapping plugin only create properties for the properties what you have in your source data. I does not create extra properties for you to handle edit or update scenarios you need to add them yourself.