# adding values from input field to observableArray and display it (knockout.js)

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

This is my first attempt at some knockout.js. There is an input field and the value you write into it gets "sent" to a list and displayed. However, it doesnt work and I guess it has to do with the fact that this.prodname is not associated correclty to the observableArray. But I cant figure out how to do that.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lt.css"/>
        <title>eins</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
        <form data-bind="submit:addValues">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:newprod, valueUpdate='afterkeydown'"></input>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:number,valueUpdate='afterkeydown'"></input>
            <button type="submit">OK</button>
        </form>
            <ul data-bind="foreach:productname">
            <li data-bind="text : $index"></li>
                <li data-bind="text:prodname"></li>
                <li data-bind="text:anzahl"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And app.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var mymodel = function() {

        this.newprod = ko.observable("");
        this.productname = ko.observableArray(""):

        this.addValues = function() {
            this.productname.push(this.newprod());
        };

    };
    ko.applyBindings(new mymodel());
});
```

I tried this, too:

```
this.productname.push({newprod: this.newprod() });
```

After reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419438/adding-an-item-to-an-observablearray-in-knockoutjs-when-using-mapping

As far as I can tell, my code resembles this example:
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html

However, I dont want the observableArray to be prepopulated. I want the values to come from the input field.

Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/4P9hH/1/))

Your code wasn't working because in the `data-bind="foreach:productname"` list that you had, you were trying to bind to properties of your viewmodel (one instance) instead of properties/observables of the array that you wanted to iterate over. There were also some other things, like `data-bind="text:prodname"` yet no `prodname` was defined anywhere in your view model. I cleaned it some for you, and hopefully you can adapt this code to meet your needs.

```
var mymodel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.newprod = ko.observable();
    self.anzahl = ko.observable();
    self.productname = ko.observableArray();

    self.addValues = function () {
        self.productname.push(new product(self.newprod(), self.anzahl()));

        // clear the input boxes for the next entry
        self.newprod('');
        self.anzahl('');
    };
};

function product(name, anz){
    var self = this;
    self.newproduct = ko.observable(name);  
    self.anzahl = ko.observable(anz);
}

ko.applyBindings(new mymodel());
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <form data-bind="submit:addValues">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:newprod"></input>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:anzahl"></input>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
    <ul data-bind="foreach:productname">
        <li data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: newproduct"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: anzahl"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, allright, I need to pass a new object in the push-method... now I see it. Thanx a lot!!